# Error when trying to create publishing site on sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

[image]

Getting this error in sharepoint 2016 after migrating from 2013.

Need help please .

Working on it...

This animation indicates the operation is in progress. Click to remove this animated image.  This shouldn't take long.

---

### Server Error in '/' Application.

0x8107058aProvisioning did not succeed. Details: Failed to initialize some site properties for Web at Url: 'http://tst-sps16.works.test/test' OriginalException: A cobalt error was thrown. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 0x8107058aProvisioning did not succeed. Details: Failed to initialize some site properties for Web at Url: 'http://tst-sps16.works.test/test' OriginalException: A cobalt error was thrown.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[COMException (0x8107058a): 0x8107058aProvisioning did not succeed. Details: Failed to initialize some site properties for Web at Url: 'http://tst-sps16.works.test/test' OriginalException: A cobalt error was thrown.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +316

[SPException: Provisioning did not succeed. Details: Failed to initialize some site properties for Web at Url: 'http://tst-sps16.works.test/test' OriginalException: A cobalt error was thrown.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +170
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +818
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate featureWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors) +1213
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors) +573
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.ApplyWebTemplateAndRedirect(SPWeb Web, String strWebTemplate, Nullable`1 bSharedNav, Boolean bOnTopNav, Boolean bOnQuickLaunch, Page page, Boolean bDeleteOnError, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors) +2604
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.NewSubwebPage.BtnCreateSubweb_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1021
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +129
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4949

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0

Comment: Please add full error-text to the question. The picture is hard to read and doesn't contain the full error-message.

Comment: try to clear configuration cache on the sharepoint servers https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/clearing-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache/

Comment: Tried what you suggested @waqas sarwar. Still gave the same error.